# Cannot change color in TextView android

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to change particular text in `textview` ,i  tried like this,

xml file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="30dp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textSize="8sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Java file

```
try {
   String first_text = "<font color='#ffcc33'><b>"+"ANDROID"+ "</b></font>";
   String second_text = "<font color='#33689C'>"+"MARSHAMLLOW"+ "</font>";
   Tv_text.setText(Html.fromHtml(first_text+second_text));
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

what the wrong with this,the text color not changed.give any suggestion.

Comment: You can use `findViewById` and call it after `setCeontentView` .

Comment: where is your textview which have id "Tv_text" ??

Comment: if some one know the answer just post here ,why u are downvoting this question and whats the wrong with this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if you use modifiers below  like this make sure it false state :

 android:textAllCaps="true"  

 runtime u have to set Allcaps="true";
```

Comment: Your Question is **"what the wrong with this,the text color not changed."** but your answer is different.. So please ask question clearly....

Comment: while setting a color on your textview(part of text in textview) using html.fromHtml() or Spannable ,if  android:textAllCaps="true"  ,it will not change the text color,first of all u hav to try this after will decide  whether this answer is wrong or right @Raja

Comment: Again see your Question **"Cannot change color in TextView android"**, if your asking **"After changing the text color in TextView then text is not showing in AllCaps format"**. I think This is a correct Question.

Comment: ofcourse you are right,but if  you read my description of question you didnt ask this question,any way thanks for your valuable feedback @Raja

Answer (score 0):

this is the easiest way to change text color :

```
your_textview.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
```

you can change the color with many ways :

```
your_textview.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
your_textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
your_textview.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
```